# Crash when passing a Lua function as a callback, works well with C++ lambdas

Tags: c++, lua

EDIT: Calling `fn` on `set` works, the Lua function is called. The problem is on the timer's callback.

I suspect this conversion[*] from "std::function" to "void *" is the problem.

```
&const_cast<std::function<void()> &>(fn)
```

Because on the timer's callback I got an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

---

CONFIRMED: The problem is between the conversion between std::function to void pointer.

Is there a safe way to do this? I would like to use SDL timers.

---

I'm using the sol2 library to create bindings between Lua and C++. I've created a class called `timermanager`, where the `set` function works perfectly with C++ lambdas. However, now I want to be able to pass a Lua callback to C++, but it crashes on the line with `(*fn)();`. I also tried using `sol::function`, which is supposedly more flexible than `std::function`, but it crashes at the same line.

The binding works, and the timer is correctly configured with the interval I pass.

I suspect it might have something to do with Lua's garbage collector. It's possible that the collector is sweeping and taking the callback function with it. However, it's strange because below I have an `engine.run()` that gets stuck in a loop.

```
#include <sol/sol.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>


uint32_t wrapper(uint32_t interval, void *param) {
  auto fn = static_cast<std::function<void()> *>(param);
  (*fn)();
  return interval;
}

class timermanager {
public:
  timermanager() = default;
  virtual ~timermanager();

  void set(int32_t interval, const std::function<void()> &fn) {
  const auto id = SDL_AddTimer(interval, wrapper, &const_cast<std::function<void()> &>(fn));
  if (id == 0) {
    throw std::runtime_error("[SDL_AddTimer] failed to set timer");
  }

  _timers[id] = fn;
}

private:
  std::map<int32_t, std::function<void()>> _timers;
};

class scriptengine {
public:
  scriptengine() = default;
  virtual ~scriptengine() = default;

  void run() {
    _lua.set_function("set", &timermanager::set, &_timermanager);

    const auto script = R"(
        local e = engine:new()

        set(1000, function()
            print("on_timer")
        end)

        e:run() # runs forever here
    )"

  SDL_Event event;

  while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
    switch (event.type) {
    case SDL_QUIT:
        exit();
        break;
    }
  }

private:
  sol::state _lua;

  timermanager _timermanager;
};

int main() {
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_TIMER);

    scriptengine se;
    se.run();

    return 0;
}
```

MRE https://godbolt.org/z/Kb8P565c8

Comment: You are right. I am using sol2, it should get translated automatically though.

Comment: From what I remeber about LUA .. even if you actuaally was passing functional object to a function, `set` isn't an environment managed by lua, it gets destroyed on exit.Generally you have to register a function with C\C++ side to call it from C++, not sure how sol2  manages that.

Comment: The function call works, Lua is capable to call "set" fine. The problem is on the line "(*fn)();", which crashes because the fn is invalid. "(*fn)();" WORKS when I use it with a C++ lambda.

Comment: `SDL_AddTimer(interval, wrapper, &const_cast<std::function<void()> &>(fn));` ends up passing the address of a potentially temporary functor to `wrapper` - this is completely unsafe and most likely broken. You need to store the functor elsewhere, where its lifetime is guaranteed to last at least until `wrapper` is called, and pass that address instead (or use a different approach in general). Also you will most likely need `sol::function` to ensure the Lua GC does not collect the temporary function expression before it will be used

Comment: @Rodrigo read what UnholySheep wrote, I meant same thing. Even with lambda your approach works only if it's a captureless one  (and any async call would have a problem if a copy of capturing lambda wasn't saved somewhere, because it would cease to exist after exit from `set`. An inline function in LUA is a rough equivalent of  capturing lambda in C++.

Comment: Got it. So, I am going to change my approach and store the fn on the class instead of passing it as void *. Thanks!